# PHP5.3 : How to use PDO singleton class (indirectly) from the main source code

Tags: php, class, singleton, pdo

Using PHP5.3.3, I have 2 classes, called *SinglePDO* and *Manager*, both working, but I'd certainly need your advices to optimize those unefficient code scriptings. Hence I have 2 questions but I guess strictly related one to another  :

---

**1) Access to the *SinglePDO* methods from a *Manager* object in the main code**

From the main code :

```
$test=new Manager('mydbname', $some_parameters);
$dbfields = $test->getFieldsSummary(false);
```

In the *Manager* class, redefined function, provided it's defined in the *SinglePDO* class :

```
public function getFieldsSummary($param)
{
    return $this->_dbh->getFieldsSummary($param);
}
```

**Question:**
How to get rid of the necessity to redefine all *SinglePDO* methods in the *Manager* class ?
(I have tried : *class Manager extends SinglePDO* and using : **__call()** but w/o success)

---

**2) Split *SinglePDO* into 2 classes**
The *SinglePDO* class embeds lots of methods. I'd like to unpack these methods and throw them into another class, say *Tool* overloading the *SinglePDO* class with method 1, method_2, etc...

**Question :**
How to achieve this in the previous context (still having the Manager Class)

---

Here is the *SinglePDO* class, a typical one but with additional methods.

```
       class SinglePDO extends PDO {
            private static $_dsn    = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=foobar';
            private static $_dbuser= 'dbuser' ;
            private static $_dbpwd  = 'dbpwd' ;
            private static $_lock = true;

        public function __construct( $dsn , $uname, $upass ) {

           if( self::$lock ) {
            trigger_error( 'Forbidden Class usage (singleton)');
           }
           parent::__construct( $dsn , $uname, $upass  );

        }

    public static function getInstance($dbh) {
        if( self::$instance == NULL ){
            self::$lock= FALSE;
                    self::$instance = new SinglePDO(self::$_dsn, self::$_dbuser, self::$_dbpwd);
                    self::$lock = TRUE;
        }
    return self::$instance;
    }

    /* lots of added methods that I'd like to drop into a Tool class  */
    public function my_method_1($param) {
     // do this and that
    }
} /* end of the uggly class */
```

**EDIT**:
In btwn, I found this [very interesting link](http://www.selfcontained.us/2011/04/20/php-and-an-abstract-singleton/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, did you use call in conjunction with call_user_func_array? Because this has worked for me in projects before:

```
function __call( $fname, array $fargs )
{
    return call_user_func_array( array( $this->_dbh, $fname ), $fargs );
}
```

To question two: Well, if you get an answer to question 1 you will be able to get an answer to this as well. I might have something like:

```
class PDOTool
{
    /* why does getInstance have a parameter? */
    private static $pdo = SinglePDO::getInstance(NULL);

    public static my_method_1($param) {
       self::$pdo->doSomething($param);
    }
    /**  __callStatic works in PHP >= 5.3.0  */
    public function __callStatic( $fname, array $fargs )
    {
        return call_user_func_array( array( self::$pdo, $fname ), $fargs );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx: hum, I guess "No" as I used the __call magic method in a wrong way, so I'll try this.

Comment: thx: __call( $fname, array $fargs ) with the right code works like a charm but it looks like this has a side effect: it gives a far slower execution time than redefining the function in the parent class.

Comment: getInstance have parameters as my "singleton" is actually designed to provide bindings to several db servers. Say "half-singleton"..

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question #1: If you extend a class with another, all `public` and `protected` methods will be available in the sub-class without re-defining them.

Answer to question #2 is to extend the classes one after another.

```
class Tools extends SinglePDO {}

class Manager extends Tools {}
```

BTW: weird [implementation of a singleton pattern in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php).

Comment: Thx but that's exactly my point: I can't access the SinglePDO public method from the source code if I do not redefine it in the Manager class. For teh second point, I want to split the SinglePDO-class as it's a big file but most of teh time I just need a small part of the containing tools. So I'd like to create several toolboxes that I can apply to a PDO object, depending on the needs, and avoiding loading huge classes.

Comment: @hornetbzz "…can't access the SinglePDO public method […] if I do not redefine it in the Manager class." Thats strange, as it works in all my extended classes. Its also the [documented behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php), that you may call an inherited method from the sub-class. Maybe there is some other sort of error.

Comment: No idea why this extension is not working - I need to investigate further.